# Add timestamp with duration in sqlalchemy + postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to add a timestamp with an integer duration in my query.

```
QTrack.query.filter(
  func.dateadd(
    QTrack.start_time, QTrack.duration * func.interval('1 second')
  ) < datetime.datetime.now()
).order_by(
  QTrack.start_time.desc()
).limit(
  5
)
```

It is having issues on `QTrack.duration * func.interval('1 second')`

I am running Postgres as my db.

Comment: and what is the problem?.